# Setting the correct type for an empty tuple that later becomes a tuple of a specific type

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a python function that looks as following:

```
from typing import Tuple

def test() -> Tuple[int]:
    o: Tuple[int] = ()
    for i in range(2):
        o+=(i,)
    return o
```

Evaluating this with mypy returns the errors

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[]", variable has type "Tuple[int]")
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[int, int]", variable has type "Tuple[int]")
```

Assigning the tuple and return value the type Tuple without the int specification resolves this problem. I would like to specify the contents of the tuple as well though. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# For tuples of variable size, we use one type and ellipsis
x: tuple[int, ...] = (1, 2, 3)  # Python 3.9+
x: Tuple[int, ...] = (1, 2, 3)
```

From:

https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html

Answer (score 0):

With regard to type hints, `Tuple` is not like `List`.

`Tuple[int]` means "a `tuple` of 1 `int`"

`Tuple[int, int]` means "a `tuple` of 2 `int`s"

`List[int]` means "a `list` of `int`s"